# How to extract strings before and after whitespace, special characters?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, regex-group

I have a dataframe "trial_df" with below column values as below:

```
Names

GHAITHA & AL MOOSA
ASEEL ELECTRONICS T
SUNRISE SUPERMARKET-QU
EMARAT-AL SAFIYAH(6735
LULU CENTRE LLC EFT TE
MAX
THEMAX
THE LULU
GHAITHA 123
SUNRISE %$#
```

Requirement :

1) Extract only strings before and after whitespace, special characters.

For eg: "ASEEL ELECTRONICS T" will become "ASEEL ELECTRONICS

2) But only on below conditions :

a) the second string length should be greater than 2

b) the second string should be alphanumeric

Eg : 'GHAITHA & AL MOOSA' will be just 'GHAITHA' as the second string after white space is '&' ( both conditions fails : Not alphanumeric and length is not greater than 2)

Eg: 'MAX' will be 'MAX' as its only one string. similarly 'THE LULU' will be same as its already just 2 strings.

Final output :

```
Names

GHAITHA
ASEEL ELECTRONICS
SUNRISE SUPERMARKET-QU
EMARAT
LULU CENTRE
MAX
THEMAX
THE LULU
GHAITHA
SUNRISE
```

My function to do the requirement :

```
def remove_strings(df, col):
    for i in df.index:
        x = df.at[i, col]
        x = x.split(' ')
        if len(x) > 1:
            if len(x[1]) > 2:
                x[1] = ''.join(e for e in x[1] if e.isalnum())
                x = ' '.join(x[0:2])
                df.at[i, col] = x
            else:
                df.at[i, col] = x[0]
        else:
            df.at[i, col] = df.at[i, col]

#calling my function 
remove_strings(df=trial_df, col='Names')
```

Issue with my function : Though it solves the requirement, but its not well optimized.
My data is of more than 1 million rows, so its looping that many times which is very time consuming.
Is there a very good optimized way to solve my requirement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 df.Names.replace(regex=r'^(\w+)(\s[A-Z-]{2,})?.*',value=r'\1\2')
Out[186]: 
0                   GHAITHA
1         ASEEL ELECTRONICS
2    SUNRISE SUPERMARKET-QU
3                    EMARAT
4               LULU CENTRE
5                       MAX
6                    THEMAX
7                  THE LULU
8                   GHAITHA
9                   SUNRISE
Name: Names, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression we might be wishing to design here is quite complicated. Maybe, it would be best to break down the task, then we would design much simpler expressions. For instance, `THE LULU` case can be simply ruled out before we run it through the regex engine.

My partial try for an expression is:

```
^([A-Z\s]{3,}?)(&.+|\s[A-Z]{1}$|-.+|\s[A-Z]{3}\s.+|\s[0-9].+|\s[~!@#$%^&*]+.+)$
```

But, I'm quite sure that it won't work in some other inputs that we may have and not listed here.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/QrYmpi/1/)

---

The idea would have three steps:

- We take those which are simple to find/filter out, such as "THE LULU"
- We add a capturing group with most amount of boundaries `^([A-Z\s]{3,}?)`
- We add another group with sub-expressions connected with logical ORs and filter out what we wish to be out at the end of our string.

[image]